# Google Spreadsheet ArrayFormula doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

the following formula is totally working as a normal formula.
As soon as I try to do it as a ArrayFormula all cells stay empty.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND($L2:$L="yes",ISNUMBER($O2:$O)),WORKDAY.INTL(IF(ISNUMBER($Z2:$Z),$Z2:$Z,IF(ISNUMBER($Y2:$Y),$Y2:$Y,"")),($O2:$O*(IF($A2:$A<>"",IF($P2:$P="day",1,IF($P2:$P="week",5,IF($P2:$P="month",20,0))),"")))),IF(AND($P2:$P<>"",ISNUMBER($O2:$O)),IF(ISNUMBER($Z2:$Z),$Z2:$Z,IF(ISNUMBER($Y2:$Y),$Y2:$Y,""))+$O2:$O,"")))
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF( --($L2:$L="yes") * --(ISNUMBER($O2:$O), if true, if false))`

`and` logic doesn't work in `ArrayFormula`

- instead of `AND` use `*`
- instead of `OR` use `+`
- `--` to convert `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`

Comment: Thank you very much! With this logic it is working now.

Comment: You can leave out the -- because the multiplication already coerces the true/false to one/zero